# Given a process what is the stochastic differential equation it fulfils?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Given the process $X_t = (2+t+\exp(W_t))_t$ where $W_t$ is Brownian motion. How can I find the SDE that it fulfils.
I am actually looking for two functions $\sigma, \tau$ such that
$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \sigma(W_s,s)dW_s + \int_0^t\tau(W_s,s)ds$. Is there any straight forward way to get them?
Cheers

Comment: What did you try? There is basically one way to go, no?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Apply Itô's formula to $f(t,x) := 2+t+e^x$. This gives you an expression of the form

$$X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \sigma(s,e^{W_s}) \, dW_s + \int_0^t b(s,e^{W_s} ) \, ds.$$

Now use that

$$e^{W_s} = X_s-2-s.$$

Comment: Not sure the last step is on-topic since (oddly) the OP wants drift and diffusion functions depending on W, not X...

Comment: @Did True enough; but I guess it's merely a typo in the OPs question. Let's see...

Comment: Hmmm... The possibility of a typo is real so, as you say, let us wait and see... :-)